# Regenerate checkboxes in listview from last session

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I generate a working listview from an adapter with checkboxes:

```
final ArrayList<String> ArrayListHouse = new ArrayList<String>();
do
{
String ColumnNameTemp = myDBcursor.getString(ColumnIndexName);
ArrayListHouse.add(ColumnNameTemp);
}while (myDBcursor.moveToNext());

ListView = new ListView(getActivity());
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, ArrayListHouse);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now I want do regenerate the state of the checkboxes when the app comes
up after a stop. It is no problem for me to save the checked checkboxes
with sharedprefs or my database. But I have a lot of trouble trying to
load the list with the predefined checkboxes. What is the right mechanism?
Any examples?

Bye Karsten

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setItemChecked(int, boolean)
Here is what you need:

```
AbsListView.setItemChecked(int, boolean)
```

by the way, how many checkboxes do you have? probably it would be better to put them in LinearLayout and ScrollView manually ?

Comment: It's a list generated from my sqlite-database with 170 entries. What do you mean: should I replace my listview with abslistview? Could you write down a small example?

Comment: You do not need replace yourListView by AbsListView, since AbsListViewv is a superclass of yourListView. However, you must know the way to identify item only, for instance using an id, and map this id for the item position. Another possibilty is implements your own ListAdapter.